# onEnter/onExit method in React Native Component (react-native-router-flux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

So I can use the onEnter/onExit method at the root of my app in the router definitions and it works perfectly fine:

```
<Scene key="arena" hideNavBar={true}  onEnter={() => console.log("Entered")} component={ArenaPage} />
```

Is there any way I can do this inside the component itself so that I can update the local state??

```
export default class ArenaPage extends Component {
    onEnter () {
        this.setState(...)
    }
    // Render blah blah blah...
}
```

If not possible, Is there anyway to trigger componentWillUnmount when navigating away from Scene (Actions.[key])

Answer (score 3):

You can use `onEnter` and `onExit` methods to get the result you want. And in turn can access `this` like so.

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'

class Home extends Component {
  static onEnter() {
     // homeSceneKey needs to be the same key that you use to configure the Scene
     Actions.refs.homeSceneKey.getWrappedInstance().myFunction()
  };

  myFunction = () => {
     // have access to this (props and state) here
     this.blah = "what ever you want to do"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Pre-requisite: withRef need to be set to true, otherwise getWrappedInstance() will not be available.


connect(null, null, null, { withRef: true })(Home);

Comment: @Xavier (according to the redux doc withRef has been changed to forwardRef)

I have added a {forwardRef: true}, and it still doesn't work, Actions.refs are always empty... any help??

Comment: same here @DanielB.

Comment: same for me Actions.refs is always empty

Answer (score 2):

Please check latest `react-native-router-flux:beta.27`, now you can define onEnter, onExit methods as your react component methods.

```
class Home extends Component {
  static onEnter() {
    console.log('On Focus Enter')
  };
  static onExit() {
    console.log('On Focus Exit')
  }
}
```

Comment: you can not access `this` in `onExit()`

Comment: yes you can, refer to my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54272466/329054

Answer (score 0):

Simple use componentWillUnmount, in the arenaPage component.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    // add your code here.
}
```

Because that will run when navigation away from the component.
I am using it to remove error messages. And that works.

Comment: My problem is solved, forgot about this. componentWillUnmount will also not work here as the component is not umounted when transitioning to next scene with `Actions.[key]`

Comment: @NathanHorrigan How did you solve this problem? can you suggest?

Comment: @PorawatChimcherdsin I'm setting my initial state in `componentWillMount` (for initial render) and then when I transition away from scene I have an `onDestroy` function that returns a promise that resets the scene to its initial state.

Comment: @NathanHorrigan Does that onDestroy function automatically get called? as I didn't get any like that