# React Native: API is not calling on 2nd time(fetch/axios)

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am creating react-native app using fetch method to get the data from API but when I am build the app(remove and install new app) that time it is calling API called but on 2nd time it is not.
I have also uses

```
componentDidMount, componentWillMount
```

but not work for me. following is my code:

```
export default test extends Component{
_isMounted = false;
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      showList:[]
 }
}
componentDidMount() {
    let currentComponent = this;
     currentComponent._isMounted = true;
    fetch(API_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then((response) => { return response.json()})
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.warn("responseJson: ", responseJson);
        if(currentComponent._isMounted){
         currentComponent.setState({showList: responseJson.data});
        }

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }); 

}
componentWillUnmount(){
    this._isMounted = false
}
```

}

I have add full code here. this is only called on first time, after that it will get only from cache(I think).Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: `componentDidMount` is only called once. Also note that `componentWillMount` is deprecated and you should not use it.

Comment: ohh! Thanks.
But how can I call the API when I am go to that screen?

Comment: which navigator are you using?

Comment: react-native-router-flux

Comment: Are you using a stack navigator? if then stack navigator uses cache like mechanism that is loading the screens in the stack if they are pre-visited. Or else can you post the full code here.

Comment: Yes. I have added full code here. @buddhiv

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into the [onEnter](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#scene) hook on your scene using `react-native-router-flux`.

Something like this should work:

```
class Test extends Component {
  static onEnter() {
    fetch(API_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then((response) => { return response.json()})
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.warn("responseJson: ", responseJson)
        if (currentComponent._isMounted) {
         currentComponent.setState({ showList: responseJson.data })
        }

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
  }
}
```

(if you need to access `this` in the method, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54272466/2623736) is an idea)